# Query nested pointes

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to query a nested pointer.

I have three Classes in total.

1) Carts
2) Paints
3) Colours

The Carts class has a paint pointer. The Paints class has a colour pointer.

I'd like to do one query which fetches paint and colour attributes. The first time we iterate through the collection from the fetch.success method the attributes property contains the pointed object. Next time we run it's only an array and it looses the pointed object. This time the colour pointer has lost all it's properties.

```
    updateCart: function(){
        var query = new Parse.Query(Cart);
        query.equalTo("user", app.models.user);
        query.include(["paint.colour"]);

        this.collection.query = query;  

        // Fetch class data from Parse
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: this.render
        });
    },
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your iterate method? It's not in the code you provided.

Comment: @kodingralph I've added the code below. I think the issue might be to do with backbone being able to save nested models.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch: function() {
            var query = new Parse.Query(this.model);
            query.include(["paint.colour"]);
            query.equalTo("user", app.models.user);

            query.find({
                success: this.populateCollection
            });
        },

        populateCollection: function(results){
            _.each(results, function(result){
                app.collections.cart.add(result);
            });
        },
```